# Sec0nd Data Accessing error in my view page

Tags: javascript

I have fetched some 10 records from database and accessed in view page using foreach.But i can only give approve to first record not other records.Why it is not happening.

this is my view page

```
<tr><tbody>
     <?php`enter code here`
     if(isset($result))
     {
         foreach($result as $value){?>

                <td><?php echo $name;?>  </td>
                <td><?php echo $value->date1;?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $value->purpose;?>  </td>
                <td><?php echo $value->amount;?>  </td>
                <td><?php echo $value->rep_date;?> </td>
                <?php  if($value->temp==1){?>
                           <td> Approved </td>
                           <td><?php echo $value->id;?> </td>

                 <?php  } else {?>
                          <td> 
                          <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'Admin/updatestatus';?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name ="hid" id="hid" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>">
                          <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" class="btn green" value="Approve" > 
                          </td>

                   <?php }?> 

                   <td> chat </td>
                   </tr>

       <?php } }?>

</tbody>
```

This is my controller

```
function updatestatus()
{

  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->load->model('lpmodel');
  $frmdate=$this->session->userdata('from');
  $todate=$this->session->userdata('to');
  $status=$this->session->userdata('stat');
 $emp_id=$this->session->userdata('id');
  $hidid=$this->input->post('hid');
  echo $hidid;
  $data=array(
    'temp'=>'1');
  $query=$this->lpmodel->ad_aprove_data($emp_id,$data,$hidid); 
  if($query==true)
  { //echo "hi";
       ?> <script>
      alert('Approved');
      </script><?php 
    //$value['result']=$this->lpmodel->selectapproverow($id);
    $name=$this->session->userdata('name');
    $value['name']=$name;
    //$status=$this->session->set_userdata('stat');
    $value['result']=$this->lpmodel->ad_selectreimb($emp_id,$status,$frmdate,$todate);
    $this->load->view('ad_reimbursement',$value);
  }
  else
  {// echo "error";

      ?> <script>
      alert('Try Again');
      </script><?php 
         $value['new']=$this->lpmodel->fetchname();
      $this->load->view('ad_reimbursement',$value); 

  }
```

}

Comment: Seems to me you are generating alot of elements with same ids (hid, sub). Html-document does not allow multiple elements with same id. Also form-element is missing ending tag.

Comment: i have different id in the table which is an unique id,that id is 'hid'.Sub id is used to submit.In addition to this i have posted partial coding in view page so form tag is missing.

Comment: I don't follow, you say you are using id "hid" for the table, but according to your example, "hid" is the id of the hidden field. And it's inside a loop, so every hidden-field generated will have id "hid", which is illegal. Also all the submit buttons will also have id "sub", which is also illegal.